Short story about a battle being decided by a random action of a sleep deprived soldier
I did read it maybe 5-10 years ago but on the internet, in English, so I cannot tell you which magazine it was from.
There was some of exposition about two sides preparing for a space battle. Both sides are managed by computers. The computers tell them about positioning, reinforcements, and the like. Everything is controlled, and a success probability is known to both sides.
IIRC the story is explained by the commanding officer of one side. He says that he is doing whatever the computer is telling him, but because his side has lower resources/reinforcements, projections for success are going down. Since his odds are bad, he must avoid battle, so the enemy can improve its position little by little (further worsening his odds). As both sides are governed by computers, he knows that he cannot start the action because his odds are low, but also that when the other side's odds are good enough, the battle with start and he will be wiped out.
In the end, one of the soldiers in the "losing" side is so tired that he acts against orders and the batle starts (even if his side has little chance of winning). Since this was an unexpected move, the computers had not taken it into account for their calculation, the "underdog" side ends winning the battle. IIRC, it turns out that the general had set things so that kind of thing would happen, thinking that in his situation acting randomly offered a better chance than acting rationally.

@Valorum absolutely spot on, thank you! What do you want me to do with the question? Delete, close as dupe, wait for your answer?

Don't delete it as your question had different details to the other. I'm voting to close it as a dupe.

I thought he grabbed the control mike and shouted out "all ships, attack at will, fire at will, this order cannot be countermanded" and then he snapped off the microphone. The staff could only gape as  ships shot off at strange angles, randomly firing at the enemy
